# Error while installing Cassandra (Invalid initial heap size: -Xms4096M)

Tags: java, cassandra

I am trying to run Cassandra on my windows, but I keep on getting this error.

```
Failed 64-bit check. Re-running to get version from 32-bit
Invalid initial heap size: -Xms4096M
The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Can anyone explain why I am facing this and how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds to me like your `JAVA_HOME` variable is pointing to a 32-bit JRE.  Reverify/install your Java installation, making sure to use a 64-bit version.

If you're using Cassandra 3, Java 8 is the highest main version that it will work with.  If you're on Cassandra 4, this is going to be difficult to run natively as Windows support was completely removed from that version.